# error 400 in react hooks and Asp core api nested data

Tags: reactjs

**Good day ,**
I have issue " error 400 " when trying to post data with react hooks and axios .I think there is a problem with onSubmit function or Onchange .My api is represent a one to many table.
My api is : asp core api whith swagger output :

```html
{
  "trackingID": 0,
  "trackingDate": "2022-09-19T12:08:38.063Z",
  "orders": [
    {
      "orderId": 0,
      "orderNo": 22,
      "ordertotal": 22,
      "paymentId": 1,
      
      "trackingID": 0,
      "driverId": 1
      
    }
  ],
  "expensesses": [
    {
      "expId": 0,
      "petrol": 22,
      "service": 22,
      "trackingID": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

**Here is my react useState:**

```
const [trackings,setTracking] = useState({
trackingDate: "",
        orders:[
          {
            
            orderNo: "",
            ordertotal: "",
            paymentId: "",
            driverId: "",
            
          }
        ],
        expensesses:[
          {
            
            petrol: "",
            service: "",
           
          }
        ]
```

});

here is my form :

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="num1" className="form-label">
          Date
          </label>
          <input
            type={"date"}
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter Date"
            name="trackingDate"
            value={trackings.trackingDate}
            onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="Date" className="form-label">
          Order No
          </label>
          <input
            type={"text"}
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter Order No"
            name="orderNo"
            value={trackings.orders.orderNo}
            onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="num1" className="form-label">
          Order Total
          </label>
          <input
            type={"text"}
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter Order Total"
            name="ordertotal"
            value={trackings.orders.ordertotal}
            onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="paymentId" className="form-label">
               Select Payment
        </label>
        <select
         name="paymentId"
         value={trackings.orders.paymentId}
         className="form-control"
         onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
        >
        <option value="">Select Payment</option>
        {
         
         payment.map(payment =>{
            return(
              <option key={payment.paymentId} value={payment.paymentId}>{payment.paymentName}</option>
            )
          })
        }
        </select>
        
      </div>
       
      <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="driverId" className="form-label">
        Select Driver
        </label>
        <select
        name="driverId"
        value={trackings.orders.driverId}
        className="form-control"
        onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
        >
         
        <option value="">Select Driver</option>
        {
          
          drivers.map(driver =>{
            return(
              <option key={driver.driverId} value={driver.driverId}>{driver.driverName}</option>
            )
          })
        }
        </select>
        
      </div>

      <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="petrol" className="form-label">
        petrol Total
        </label>
        <input
          type={"text"}
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter Petrol Total"
          name="petrol"
          value={trackings.expensesses.petrol}
          onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="service" className="form-label">
        service Total
        </label>
        <input
          type={"text"}
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter Services Total"
          name="service"
          value={trackings.expensesses.service}
          onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
        />
      </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-primary">
          Submit
        </button>
        <Link className="btn btn-outline-danger mx-2" to="/AllTrackings">
          Cancel
        </Link>
      </form>
```

*My onChange function :*

```
const onInputChange = (e) => {
setTracking({ ...trackings, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
```

};

> onSubmit function :

```html
const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios.post('https://localhost:7139/api/Trackings', trackings);
    
    navigate("/AllTrackings");
  };
```

here is backend logs when doing post request
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (94ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = DateTime2)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Trackings] ([TrackingDate])
VALUES (@p0);
SELECT [TrackingID]
FROM [Trackings]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [TrackingID] = scope_identity();
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = Int32), @p1='?' (DbType = Int32), @p2='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Expensesses] ([TrackingID], [petrol], [service])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2);
SELECT [ExpId]
FROM [Expensesses]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [ExpId] = scope_identity();
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = Int32), @p1='?' (DbType = Int32), @p2='?' (DbType = Int32), @p3='?' (DbType = Int32), @p4='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Orders] ([DriverId], [OrderNo], [Ordertotal], [PaymentId], [TrackingID])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4);
SELECT [OrderId]
FROM [Orders]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [OrderId] = scope_identity();

Many thanks

Comment: Could you share what your backend logs when you make the request? It could be because you have not set the content-type header.

Comment: Sorry for late because I was sick , I edit my post with backend logs